# Help understanding property of affine function

Tags: real-analysis

How is it true that $\ell(ta+(1-t)b)=t\ell(a)+(1-t)\ell(b)$ if one only knows that $\ell(\cdot)$ is affine?

Comment: That is the definition of an affine function $l(t a + (1-t)b) = t l(a)+(1-t) l(b)$ for all $t$. An equivalent way to look at it is $l(b +t(a-b)) = l(b)+ t (l(a)-l(b))$.

Comment: @copper.hat I've honestly never seen such a definition of an affine function. Do you mind referring me to some literature that I can read? :)

Comment: There are various definitions, all equivalent at some level. For example, Rockafellar, "Convex Analysis", Section 4 defines an affine function (on an affine set) to be finite, convex and concave. Boyd & Vandenberghe, "Convex Optimization", 2.3.2 defines an affine function to be one that is the sum of a linear function and a constant. Rudin, "Functional Analysis", ch.5 at the start of the Kakutani's fixed point theorem defines it as I have (albeit a little more restricted for his particular application).

Comment: I prefer the one I used as it can be viewed as application to an affine combination being the same as an affine combination of the application.

Comment: @copper.hat Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $\ell(x)=Mx+C$ is affine, then by direct computation
\begin{align} \ell(a) &= Ma +C \\ \ell(b) &= Mb+C \\ t\ell(a) + (1-t)\ell(b) &= t(Ma+C) + (1-t)(Mb+c)\\&= M(ta+(1-t)b)+C\\ &= \ell(ta+(1-t)b)\end{align}
Graphically, this is just saying that any two points are connected by a line. You don't need to have chosen an origin to verify this, so you don't need the stronger assumption of linearity for this to hold.